# Windows Vista stuck beforestart up

Tags: windows-vista, boot

I have a Toshiba laptop with Windows vista, and ever since about a year ago it has been nothing but trouble.

The computer has had multiple viruses, which we have gotten fixed, even though we have had Norton 360 in the past, and now we have since switched to Kaspersky Labs. The problem I am having now looks like a problem we have had in the past, where the computer does not even begin booting up when you press the power button. The lights come on, but the screen stays blank.

I think that the virus (if it is a virus) may be called RootKit, which I have a repair disc for, although I can't run that disc with out the computer starting up. Since the screen stays blank, I can't even choose to run safe mode. If anybody has a solution I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If the screen is blank and even the manufacturer logo won't show up, then it's not a software-related problem.

Get a flashlight and someone with very good eyes. Maybe it's just the screen backlight that's out, if you point the flashlight on the screen something should be barely visible. And you should hear the Windows startup sound if you turn the volume up.

If that's not the screen, then there are numerous options. Try to disconnect the hard disk, some BIOS-es may lock up in rare cases when there's something wrong with HDD. If it won't fix the problem, then I'm afraid you have to contact service center or get a new laptop.

By the way, rootkit isn't a specific virus, but a malware type - it's a piece of software that hides itself and other malicious software.

Comment: No i dont think the screen is shot, because i hooked up a secondary monitor also. I have tried inserting a cd with TDSSKILLER, but i dont think that it ran because i couldnt give it any input without the screen working.