# Secondary monitor not working... Or so I think

Tags: windows-8, display, multiple-monitors

I've been using an Acer 1920x1080 monitor and recently bought a 1280x1024 Xerox monitor, to hold onto as a secondary monitor. I set it up, and it kind of works. I'll turn on the monitor, it'll work for 1 to 2 seconds, and then immediately shut off. I have my secondary plugged into integrated graphics, and my primary plugged into my NVIDIA GeForce 650.

Specs:

- Intel i5-3470
- GeForce GTX 650
- 480W PSU
- 8GB DDR3 RAM

Any help would be appreciated. I'll be online for a while if anyone needs additional info.

Comment: Check if the monitor works with another PC. Sounds like a backlight problem, you can [examine it with a flashlight](http://superuser.com/a/555855/194694).

Comment: I don't have another PC to test it with. I used to be a huge laptop user before making the switch by building my own desktop.

Comment: Laptops can have external screens connected too.

Comment: Not through any adapters I own or are in the position to purchase